# Mysql update decimal by increasing by value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with MySQL and need to increase a decimal (3,2) by 0.01. I've tried searching this with no success. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the problem with?

```
update table t
    set col = col + 0.01;
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that the columns were also variables, thanks! :)